# Opportunity with Contact Role report does not retrieve all expected records

Tags: reporting, opportunitycontactrole

I have 1868 Opportunities. Every one of them has at least one contact role.

When I do an Opportunities with Contact Role report I only get 1003 records.

I expect to be getting more records, not less.

I've checked that both reports are pulling all opportunities and range all time. It doesn't seem to be related to Primary Contact or any of the actual roles that people have.

What is happening here?

Comment: Can you do a Cross-Filter in Report Like This  
"Opportunities with Contact Roles"

Comment: Yup. Full Opportunity report with Cross filter of "Opportunities with Contact Roles" returns 1868 records. Unfortunately I can't get any contact ID this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I missed one of the default settings. I had the "My Opportunities" and "All time" selected properly. But my Opportunity with Contact Role was default to "include" only records that were Open.

So solution: Make sure "include" is marked "all".